# ansible authentication with different passwords

Tags: authentication, passwords, ansible

At first, this is my hostfile:

```
[servers]
server1.domain.com
server2.domain.com
```

We are not allowed to login using root, so we have to use become_user and ask_become_pass, both configured in ansible.cfg. This works fine, as long as there is one host.

When using ansible-playbook, I want to get asked for every SU-Password for every new host.

Is this possible or do I have a wrong approach?

kind regards,
Philipp

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would use `NOPASSWD` in the sudoers file to allow those users to gain privileges without a password.

If your security policies prevent that, you may want to look into [using ssh-agent to handle your sudo authorization](http://blather.michaelwlucas.com/archives/1106).

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Xiong about the best practice, it's possible to set the become pass for each in inventory

```
[servers]
server1.domain.com ansible_become_pass="mypass"
server2.domain.com ansible_become_pass="mypass"
```